# Tooltip gets cut off from ng2-chart

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to fit line charts into some very small table cells:

[image]

As you can see, the rightmost point's tooltip gets slightly cut off. This is the only one that causes a problem.

The easiest fix would probably be to put a higher z-index on the tooltip, but I've googled it and I don't think that's possible. Instead, is it possible to make the tooltip display on the left side of the point instead of below it? That's what the second to last point does:

[image]

Here are my chart options:

```
public lineChartOptions:any = {
responsive: false,
tooltips: {
  yPadding: 2,
  xPadding: 2,
  caretPadding: 5,
  caretSize: 3,
  displayColors: false,
},
layout: {
  padding: {
    left: 5,
    right: 5,
    top: 5,
    bottom: 5,
  }
},
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      //stepSize: 50,
      max: 150,
      beginAtZero: true,
      display: true,
    }
  }],
  xAxes: [{
    display: false,
  }]
}
};
```

Any help is appreciated.